# Azure: {"Invalid syntax for directory path ''\r\nParameter name: initialConfiguration"} Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to to add my log file to blob storage. When tried to get the ConnectionString in Global.asax.cs I am getting this error from oriented here :

```
DiagnosticMonitor.Start("Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString", diagnostics);
```

How can I fix that problem. "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString" is in ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg and ServiceConfiguration.Local.cscfg

To give more explanation :

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233086
  Message=Invalid syntax for directory path ''
Parameter name: initialConfiguration
  Source=Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics
  ParamName=initialConfiguration
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration.Validate(String paramName, Nullable`1 resourceSize)
       at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitor.StartWithExplicitConfiguration(DiagnosticMonitorStartupInfo startupInfo, DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration initialConfiguration)
       at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitor.Start(CloudStorageAccount storageAccount, DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration initialConfiguration)
       at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitor.Start(String diagnosticsStorageAccountConfigurationSettingName, DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration initialConfiguration)
       at Project.Web.WebRole.OnStart() in Global.asax.cs:line 104
       at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.InitializeRoleInternal(RoleType roleTypeEnum)
       at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.InitializeRole(RoleType roleType)
       at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.Implementation.Loader.RoleRuntimeBridge.<InitializeRole>b__0()
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are retrieving the connection string correctly, but your diagnostics configuration is invalid.  What are you setting for Directory configurations?

Instead of setting diagnostics configuration via code I would recommend using the wadcfg file (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh411551.aspx), or use Visual Studio (see http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2013/04/30/announcing-the-release-of-windows-azure-sdk-2-0-for-net.aspx, in particular the "Cloud Services: Improved Diagnostics Support" section).